# How to get response from PHP server asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First of all I know that there are many questions already regarding this.After reading all answers and trying it out ..but none of them worked.So I'm uploading a question here.Please don't delete it.

So,I created a html file with a form and then sent the form data using ajax jQuery to PHP file as follows.

```
$("#form-id").submit(function e() {
e.preventDefault();
var sdata=("#text_feild").val();
$.ajax({
url:"filename.php",
type:"POST",
data:sdata
});
//display the message sent by PHP
/*Use the data sent by PHP to perform   
different function*/
```

Now I want PHP to send a message to js or html or anything else.Also, I want PHP to send some Boolean data which I will be using to perform some function.

Comment: `success:` callback function? - see [documentation for jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: If I use Success: callback function it will show success when ajax sends data to php..but PHP has to process it and then send data back to the front-end

Comment: yes, that's what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send multiple data then you can do this by using array and send them json encoded and you will receive data in "success" callback function of ajax call

consider below example

ajax call

```
$("#form-id").submit(function e() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sdata=("#text_feild").val();
    $.ajax({
       url:"filename.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:sdata,
       async: true,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // check result in console
            $('#result').html((data.content) ? (data.content) : '???');
            $('#result').prop('title', data.title);
            $('#jsonstring').html('Json object: '+JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});


    <?php

        $result = array(
            'title' => 'Title',
            'status' => 0,
        );

        echo json_encode($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm not able to retrieve the variables present in PHP  in JS using your method.The console.log() method shows all data properly but I want to use a specific variable in PHP file to execute some function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powerful pure javascript browser native **[fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)**.

To retrieve **text/html**.

```js
  fetch("https://api.github.com/")
      .then(function(response) { return response.text() })
      .then(function(text) {
     console.log(text)
  })
```

To retrieve **json**.

```js
fetch("https://www.reddit.com/.json").then(v => v.json()).then((function(v){
    syn = JSON.stringify(v)
    main.innerHTML += syn
    })
  )
```

```html
<div id="main">
```

Server side the **base of a json api** would be:

```
if ($_GET["myapi"] != ""){
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  echo json_encode(["Hello","World"]);
  exit;
}
```

Calling: **mysite/?myapi=whatever**

Output: `["Hello","World"]`, with a *json header*, and [CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) enabled.

Learn more about [javascript promise(s)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)